# How do I write a merge sort?

Tags: ruby, mergesort

I am trying to implement a merge sort and am getting `stack level too deep (SystemStackError)` error when I run my code.  I am not sure what the issue may be.

```
def merge_sort(lists)
  lists if lists.count == 1

  middle  = lists[0..(lists.count / 2) - 1 ]
  left = lists[0..middle.count - 1]
  right = lists[middle.count..lists.count]

  x = merge_sort(left)
  y = merge_sort(right)
end

merge_sort [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: You forgot `return` before `lists if lists.count == 1`

Answer (score 13):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Sorting/Merge_sort#Ruby):

```
def mergesort(list)
  return list if list.size <= 1
  mid   = list.size / 2
  left  = list[0...mid]
  right = list[mid...list.size]
  merge(mergesort(left), mergesort(right))
end

def merge(left, right)
  sorted = []
  until left.empty? || right.empty?
    if left.first <= right.first
      sorted << left.shift
    else
      sorted << right.shift
    end
  end
  sorted.concat(left).concat(right)
end
```

Comment: Fwiw, OP's implementation has more problems than just missing `return` statement in the base case, and any reasonable implementation of mergesort will have two functions, one to divide and one to reassemble.

Answer (score 11):

write this

```
 return lists if lists.count == 1
```

instead of

```
 lists if lists.count == 1
```

In Ruby, from a method last statement is always returned by default. But if you want to return from the middle of any lines except the last line conditionally, you must need to use **return** keyword explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

A simplified version with comments

```
def merge_sort(arr)
  # 0. Base case
  return arr if arr.length <= 1

  # 1. Divide
  mid = arr.length / 2
  arr0 = merge_sort(arr[0, mid])
  arr1 = merge_sort(arr[mid, arr.length])

  # 2. Conquer
  output = merge(arr0, arr1)
end

def merge(l, r)
  output = []
  until l.empty? || r.empty?
    output << if l.first <= r.first
                l.shift
              else
                r.shift
              end
  end
  # The order of `concat(l)` or `concat(r)` does not matters
  output.concat(l).concat(r)
end
```

https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/merge-sort/a/divide-and-conquer-algorithms

Answer (score 0):

This is a good way to do it.  Tis a bit tricky at first, but stay at it.

```
def merge_sort list
  if list.length <= 1
    list
  else
    mid = (list.length / 2).floor
    left = merge_sort(list[0..mid - 1])
    right = merge_sort(list[mid..list.length])
    merge(left, right)
  end 
end 

def merge(left, right)
  if left.empty?
    right
  elsif right.empty?
    left
  elsif left.first < right.first
    [left.first] + merge(left[1..left.length], right)
  else
    [right.first] + merge(left, right[1..right.length])
  end
end
```