# NoMethodError undefined method empty? for NilClass

Tags: ruby, mergesort, nomethoderror

I am trying to implement a merge sort algorithm. I have the following code:

```
def merge_sort(array)
  if array.length < 2
    return array
  else
    length = array.length
    i = array[0..array.length/2-1]
    j = array[array.length/2 .. -1]
    first = merge_sort(i)
    second = merge_sort(j)

    sorted_array = []
    until first.empty? || second.empty? do
      if first[0] >= second[0]
        sorted_array << second.shift
      else
        sorted_array << first.shift
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I get a `NoMethodError for NilClass` with it.
From my understanding, the `unless` block should check for empty array, and stop execution before a `Nil` class ever occurs.

Why do I get this error?

Comment: This won't answer your problem but you can try to see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21121075/how-do-i-write-a-merge-sort#21121122)

Comment: You don't have an `unless` block.

Answer (score 1):

If `array.length < 2` then your `merge_sort` will return `array`. Otherwise, `merge_sort` will return whatever `until some_condition do ... end` evaluates to. It so happens that `until` evaluates to `nil` so your method behaves like this:

```
def merge_sort(array)
  if array.length < 2
    return array
  else
    # Do a bunch of stuff...
    return nil
  end
end
```

That means that `first` and `second` will be `nil` most of the time and there's your `NoMethodError`. Perhaps you want to return `sorted_array` after your `until`:

```
def merge_sort(array)
  if array.length < 2
    array
  else
    #...
    sorted_array = []
    until first.empty? || second.empty? do
      #...
    end
    sorted_array # <------------------- sort of important
  end
end
```

Comment: I think your answer solves the question originally asked.  There is another unrelated bug in the original code that remains.  Once `first` is empty or `second` is empty, the `until` loop ends, and the remaining elements in the one that isn't "empty" never get added.  So to fix the bug that wasn't asked about, we need to add the remaining elements of first and second to the `sorted_array` before returning it.

Comment: @MikeK I don't want to write their code for them or take away valuable debugging experience. This looks like student work to me so I don't want to give away too much, they need to learn how to build a proper set of tests and how to debug things when tests fail. I could be wrong of course.